# com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException

Tags: android, adb, robotium, spoon

```
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:752)
at com.android.ddmlib.SyncService.openSync(SyncService.java:168)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.getSyncService(Device.java:409)
at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonDeviceRunner.run(SpoonDeviceRunner.java:215)
at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonRunner.runTests(SpoonRunner.java:111)
at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonRunner.run(SpoonRunner.java:78)
at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonRunner.main(SpoonRunner.java:376)
```

I have around n number of  test cases , every run after 5th or 6th test case i got above error and spoon get stopped.

Advance thanks for help

Comment: Why flag robotium is set here?

Comment: I am using robotium for my automation, so if any one came across the same issue, they can help me . So only i set robotium flag here. Did you face the above issue in your past experiences.